# Conditional expectation of a function of two random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I have that (X, Y) are uniformly distributed in the triangle defined by the vertices $(0, 0)$, $(1, 0)$, and $(0, 1)$. I am trying to find the following expectation value:

$$ E\left( (X-Y)^2 | X \right) $$

I am able to get the joint density, marginal densities, and conditional densities fairly easily. However, I am a little confused on how to go about solving this?

Comment: As an alternative, use the second approach from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3477975). If $(X, Y) = (U, (1 - U)V)$, then
$$f_{U, V}(u, v) =
2 (1 - u) [0 < u < 1 \land 0 < v < 1], \\
\mathbb E(Y^p \mid X) =
(1 - U)^p \hspace {1.5px} \mathbb E(V^p) =
\frac {(1 - X)^p} {p + 1}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \mathbb E\left( (X-Y)^2 | X \right)= \mathbb E\left( X^2+Y^2 -2XY | X \right)=X^2+E(Y^2|X)-2XE(Y|X)$$

Since 
$E(Yf(X)|X)=f(X)E(Y|X)$ [Basic_properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties).

Comment: For $E(Y|X)$, since $0 \leq y \leq 1 - x$, does the integrating remain $\int_{0}^{1-x}{y^2 f_{Y|X}(y|x) dy}$? Or must the bounds be changed? I know that if we let $Z$ be a random variable such that $Z = Y^2$, then the integration would be over $0 \leq Z \leq (1-x)^2$ but the density would be different. Would you be able to clarify this?

Comment: $E(Y^k|X=x)=\int_0^{1-x} y^k f(y|x) dy$. You should consider that $f(y|x)$ calculated by $f(x,y)$ so $y<1-x$.